# How can i access a variable or change the state of an element(like tabNavigator) from one mxml to another mxml?

Tags: apache-flex, variables, air

How can i access a variable or change the state of an element(like tabNavigator) from one mxml to another mxml in FLEX 4.6??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each separate MXML file should be viewed as a class, since that is what they are.

In the theory of encapsulation; two classes should not directly access / change each others variables or state.  They should use an API provided by the developer of the MXML Class.

If MXML 1 is the parent of MXML 2; then MXML1 can pass data to MXML2 by setting public properties or calling public methods.

MXML2 can pass data to MXML1 by dispatching events.

If MXML1 and MXML2 are not in a parent child relationship; (AKA Both children of the same component as one example) they they should not communicate with each other directly.  They should dispatch events which the mutual parent should handle and use to set values or execute methods on it's own children.

From an encapsulation standpoint, that is how it should be done using the built in facilities of ActionScript / Flex.

What a lot of people do as part of building applications is to make use of dependency injection.  That was values that are "global to the application" can be shared among multiple components.  Another approach to doing this is to use a Singleton.  A third approach might be to make use of static values on a class; which can be accessed without accessing an instance of a class.

Comment: +1 to highlight the dispatching / listening to events.  This is considered best practice