# Calling a function inside AS from fx:component flex

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, mxml

This one is probably really simple, but I can't find online an answer. Heres what I have:

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function DestIsAirport(event:MouseEvent):void {
                navigator.pushView(AirportSelector);
            }
            protected function DestIsAddress(event:MouseEvent):void {
                navigator.pushView(DestinationInfoView);
            }
        ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

and then I have a pop up container just below that and it looks like this:

```
<fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <fx:Component className="DestAlert">
            <s:SkinnablePopUpContainer x="50" y="200">
                <s:TitleWindow title="Destination">
                    <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" paddingTop="8" paddingBottom="8" paddingLeft="8" paddingRight="8" gap="5" width="100%">
                        <s:Label text="Is your destination an airport?"/>
                    </s:VGroup>
                    <s:HGroup horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" paddingTop="40" paddingBottom="8" gap="5" width="100%">
                        <s:Button label="Yes" bottom="10" left="10" width="100" fontSize="16" click="DestIsAirport(event)"/>
                        <s:Button label="No" bottom="10" right="10" width="100" fontSize="16" click="DestIsAddress(event)"/>
                    </s:HGroup>
                </s:TitleWindow>
            </s:SkinnablePopUpContainer>
        </fx:Component>
    </fx:Declarations>
```

I want the two buttons to run different functions from the AS3 script. This produces an error:
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method DestIsAddress.
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method DestIsAirport.

How do I get those buttons to run those two functions?

Entire source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Enter Pick Up Address">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                navigator.popView();
            }
            protected function DestIsAirport(event:MouseEvent):void {
                navigator.pushView(AirportSelector);
            }
            protected function DestIsAddress(event:MouseEvent):void {
                navigator.pushView(DestinationInfoView);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <fx:Component className="DestAlert">
            <s:SkinnablePopUpContainer x="50" y="200">
                <s:TitleWindow title="Destination">
                    <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" paddingTop="8" paddingBottom="8" paddingLeft="8" paddingRight="8" gap="5" width="100%">
                        <s:Label text="Is your destination an airport?"/>
                    </s:VGroup>
                    <s:HGroup horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" paddingTop="40" paddingBottom="8" gap="5" width="100%">
                        <s:Button label="Yes" bottom="10" left="10" width="100" fontSize="16" click="close()"/>
                        <s:Button label="No" bottom="10" right="10" width="100" fontSize="16" click="close()"/>
                    </s:HGroup>
                </s:TitleWindow>
            </s:SkinnablePopUpContainer>
        </fx:Component>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:actionContent>
        <s:Button label="Back" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </s:actionContent>
    <s:TextInput top="6" horizontalCenter="-1" prompt="Address Line 1"/>
    <s:TextInput top="47" horizontalCenter="-1" prompt="Address Line 2"/>
    <s:RadioButton top="90" label="IL - Illinois" horizontalCenter="-94"/>
    <s:RadioButton top="90" label="WI - Wisconsin" horizontalCenter="72"/>
    <s:SpinnerListContainer bottom="60" width="320" height="211" horizontalCenter="0">
        <s:SpinnerList width="317" height="100%" labelField="data" selectedIndex="0">
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:Object data=""></fx:Object>
                <fx:Object data="Abbott Park"></fx:Object>
                <fx:Object data="Addison"></fx:Object>
                <fx:Object data="Algonquin"></fx:Object>
                <fx:Object data="Alsip"></fx:Object>

    </s:ArrayList>
        </s:SpinnerList>
    </s:SpinnerListContainer>
    <s:Button bottom="10" width="302" label="Next" click="(new DestAlert()).open(this, false)"
              fontSize="24" horizontalCenter="0"/>
</s:View>
```

Comment: How are you creating an instance of the component defined in the fx:Declarations section?

Comment: I've added all of my source code now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the gist is that you are trying to access functions in one component that exist in another.  You're pop up component should dispatch events which you can listen for in the main component. I feel like I've written about this dozens of time on SO.

Comment: I am completely new to Flex, I have looked around online and found nothing that helped. If you aren't gonna post a solution will you provide me a link to one of your other posts? Maybe I am searching the wrong thing but at least point in the right direction.

Comment: do you mean listen with an EventListener? How do I trigger these events?

Comment: How about my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948564/how-can-i-access-a-variable-or-change-the-state-of-an-elementlike-tabnavigator/10948684#10948684

Comment: I understand the idea behind it but I don;t know the syntax for triggering events that the parent can use to make a function call. Thanks BTW

Comment: Some reading for you: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_07.html & http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=createevents_3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declarations section is only meant for things the user isn't going to see. You need to do a couple of things.

1. Take the component in the declarations section and move it into it's own file.
2. Show an instance of the component via a popup manager.

Additionally, it's important to note that the component and the parent are going to be in completely different scopes. However, after creating a new instance of the popup component, you can use your reference to it to add listeners. The component can then dispatch events that this class can listen to, which then call the functions.

This gets more complicated because the popupmanager is a static class and will have no relation to the code you've added here. Let me know if this needs more explanation, because I almost feel like a picture is in order.

Comment: Ok, I was able to move the component to a new file, and I instance it in this method like this
destAlert = new destinationPopup;
PopUpManager.addPopUp(destAlert, this, true);
But how do I get the buttons to do something other than close the window?

Comment: You're going to need that destAlert to dispatch some custom events. Ideally, you'd be using some sort of MVC framework for your architecture, but I think that's beyond the scope of this conversation.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. From an architectural standpoint, the most ideal way would be to move the code you want it to run over to your new component file. If the code you want to run happens to be inside your first view, then you need to dispatch a custom event from your popped component that is handled by the parent (again, not technically the parent as that scoping goes out of play when you use the popupmanager). Does your code have to reside inside that parent component?

Comment: no, the only thing that has to happen is the view navigator needs to push a new view. The that is pushed depends on the users selection. For some reason though view navigator is not in that scope so I still have a problem.

Comment: I have this line to dispatch an event and it is not working:
this.dispatchEvent(new Event("AirportDestEvent"));
I get Access of possibly undefined method Event.

Comment: I could be mistaken (it's been a while since I messed with mobile), but the problem is that anything that doesn't extend a view component doesn't have a reference to the ViewNavigator (navigator). Rather than dispatching an event, you could pass a reference to that navigator onto the popped component. `code`destAlert = new destinationPopup; destAlert.navigator = this.navigator; You'd also have to have a public property on the popped component that you  type as the type of navigator you are using for your app.

Comment: I actually ended up just simply adding event listeners to the buttons through the instance of the title window class. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Good to hear you got it worked out. After you work with flex a bit more, you may want to start looking into MVC frameworks as most of them have really good ways to manage communication between components.

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating a separate action script/mxml file? That would easily solve that issue.

Comment: you mean just load another view altogether? I just want to use a popup message to open other views. I'm completely new to flex btw so...